# I easily get motion sickness/nausea/vomit when riding a bus

Tags: vomit, nausea, triggers, vertigo, motion-sickness

I know this sounds kinda weird for some reason but whenever I heard that we are having a long trip via bus I get a slight nausea eventhough we are not yet on the bus

The symptoms triggers even when I sit on the front and even on straight roads
Listening to music worsens the conditions to me
I can't even sleep whatever I tried to.

I tried taking some anti-vertigo medicines and bonine but still the problem occurs

Is there anyways to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Motion sickness is extremely common.  You seem to have a conditioned response to it where you associate the symptoms with the thought of the stimulus.  Yes there are solutions to both the conditioning and the motion sickness.

Answer (score 2):

Some ways which are said to decrease motion sickness include:

1. Try having ginger candies or ginger tea ginger
2. If possible   stare at the horizon or anything that doesn't move(stationary).
   [American academy regarding motion](http://www.entnet.org/content/dizziness-and-motion-sickness)
3. Don't see any sort of digital things or avoid reading books...
   [Regarding books and nausea](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/why-does-reading-in-a-mov/)
4. Try chewing gums or  crackers which decrease your nausea by chewing[Pubmed regarding chewing](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26818376)
5. Try inhaling  peppermint smell(if possible isopropyl alcohol similar to sanitizer smell...)
   [Isopropyl but no evidence for peppermint](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmedhealth/PMH0041569/#!po=3.33333)
6. Try getting a comfortable positions where you can stretch your legs
7. **Try taking in some fresh air**

[Foods that prevent nausea](https://www.everydayhealth.com/digestive-health/diet/foods-that-help-relieve-nausea/#01).
[Pubmed regarding ginger](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23638927).

Comment: Welcome Sonic.  The suggestions on how to prevent motion sickness are correct, but the assertion not to take bonine is not. Please provide evidence of that suggestion.  Meds like meclizine or zofran are commonly used for this purpose, and people have different toleranaces.  Including myself.  I'll review the downvote if the evidence is solid.

Comment: Thank you!  One last thing, I would like to propose an edit to the first line.  Your post is otherwise good.  Please revert the edit if you disagree.

Comment: I've proposed an edit to remove the emojis. They do not add anything to your answer, and in my eyes just make for a childish appearance. I do not know the Community stand on this, however. @DoctorWhom Thanks for including the revert message. In my eyes, this helps new users a lot more than simply editing without leaving a comment.

Comment: I removed them and any other edits